# Can't configure nginx as a proxy for tomcat with context path

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy

Having Tomcat with application accessible on http://localhost:8080/application.

Want to have access to this application via url http://app.ru. So here's nginx proxy config:

```
server {
    server_name app.ru .app.ru;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/application;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When moving to http://app.ru, it return 302 redirect to http://app.ru/application

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you need a trailing slash on your proxy_pass directive. Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/application/;` See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: great, it works! Thanks! Please transform your comment to an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @Richard Smith comment. I've forgotten the trailing slash.