# Jenkins + Nginx + sub domain without context

Tags: nginx, jenkins

**I would like to access jenkins via my.domain.fr without never see the "jenkins" context. Is this possible exclusively with Nginx configuration ?**

I have found some interesting links :

- [Can't configure nginx as a proxy for tomcat with context path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459006/cant-configure-nginx-as-a-proxy-for-tomcat-with-context-path)
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx

But it doesn't work. The best I can have is a direct access to jenkins from my.domain.fr, and as soon as I click somewhere the "jenkins" context appears. My configuration works but seems ugly because a duplication. Moreover I got the jenkins message :

> It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken

This message is due to the "jenkins" context added on the proxy_pass. But I don't know how I could do without it.

**Current configuration :**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name my.domain.fr;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen  443;
  listen  [::]:443;
  server_name my.domain.fr;

  location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the **Jenkins URL** in the `Manage Jenkins` Section? For your case it should be set to `https://my.domain.fr` I think.

Comment: Yes I tryed to play with it but it has no impact on user navigation (/jenkins seems to be hard coded). I think this URL is used to generate dynamics links in special situation only (image in email or something like that).

Comment: My idea was to let jenkins be configured in standard way, as Tomcat, and play with Nginx to adapt, but maybe it is not possible... And for information I am using [this configuration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx), the configuration presented above was just a part of what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name my.domain.fr;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen  443;
  listen  [::]:443;
  server_name my.domain.fr;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

Anything going to / is being passed to /jenkins, which is causing your issue. Simply remove the /jenkins block and update your proxy_pass declaration. This should resolve your issue, though you may still need to tweak some Jenkins internal settings.